# Python unittest branch coverage seems to miss executed generator in zip

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage, python-coverage

I don't quite understand what Python's branch coverage stats are trying to tell me. Given code of the form

```
def f(a, b):
    c = (i for i in a)
    d = (j for j in b)  # Line of interest
    return dict(zip(c, d))

print(f(['a', 'b'], [1, 2]))
```

which is imported during unit testing, Python's standard branch coverage tells me that the `# Line of interest` line is only partially covered (`n->-n` on the CLI output, "n ↛ exit [?]" in the pretty html report).

The returned dict is clearly printed out, and executing with empty lists still yields the uncovered line.

Am I misinterpreting the coverage output? Does this smell like a bug?

Python 3.5.1, Coverage 4.0.3

Comment: I agree with you. Looks like coverage doesn't properly handle the generator.

Comment: I also agree that it is a bug: https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issues/475/generator-expression-is-marked-as-not

Answer (score 5):

I've investigated this further, and I don't think it is a bug in coverage. When the first generator (`c`) terminates, `zip()` efficiently doesn't bother collecting any more values from the second generator (`d`), so branch coverage doesn't track `d` as run to completion, even though every element is actually extracted.

If you instead write:

```
def f(a, b):
    c = (i for i in a)
    d = tuple(j for j in b)  # Line of interest
    return dict(zip(c, d))

print(f(['a', 'b'], [1, 2]))
```

as one would expect the second generator is run to completion and coverage is happy, even though the output is identical.

I don't think there's a simple way around this, even if you write the generator expression out as a generator function containing the same for loop, you get a (slightly clearer) error that execution never jumped to function exit.

I think this is just a limitation of coverage and the exit conditions of generators, as it can't know whether a generator is supposed to exit, so it flags the uncovered case.